# Dynamic Date Comparison in Search filter

Tags: sxa, content-search

Using Sitecore 9.01 and SXA 1.6 , we are trying to create search scope that filter News item based on their dates ,  so each News item has start and End date and we need to display only not expired news item ex : NewsEndDate `>=` Today

is there a way to achive that , we are think of Computed filed to mark each news item as Expired or not

Comment: You would have to update this computed field periodically in order to get this feature working (not impossible but not perfect). In 1.6 there is no feature that let you solve this problem. If SXA upgrade is possible in your case you could wait for 1.7. There is one feature that could be used to implement this. If no one will provide any answer I will create one after release.

Comment: Do you find a way other than Computed Index Field?

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak dose this feature exists now in SXA 1.7.1 ?

Comment: @user1534066 yes. I think you should fina an answer here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14148/search-results-with-starting-date-equal-to-today/14164